# How do I preset the dimensions of my dataframe in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to preset the dimensions of my data frame in pandas so that I can have 500 rows by 300 columns. I want to set it before I enter data into the dataframe.

I am working on a project where I need to take a column of data, copy it, shift it one to the right and shift it down by one row. 
I am having trouble with the last row being cut off when I shift it down by one row (eg: I started with 23 rows and it remains at 23 rows despite the fact that I shifted down by one and should have 24 rows).

Here is what I have done so far:

```
bolusCI = pd.DataFrame()
##set index to very high number to accommodate shifting row down by 1
bolusCI = bolus_raw[["Activity (mCi)"]].copy()
activity_copy = bolusCI.shift(1)
activity_copy
pd.concat([bolusCI, activity_copy], axis =1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more efficient way to achieve what you are looking to do, but to directly answer your question you could do something like this to init the DataFrame with certain dimensions

`pd.DataFrame(columns=range(300),index=range(500))`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define the `index` and `columns` in the constructor.  The simplest way is to use `pandas.RangeIndex`.  It mimics `np.arange` and `range` in syntax.  You can also pass a `name` parameter to name it.

[***`pd.DataFrame`***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)
[***`pd.Index`***](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.RangeIndex(500),
    columns=pd.RangeIndex(300)
)

print(df.shape)

(500, 300)
```